How do I force GTK apps to use Wayland compositor borders
I'm using a "minimalist" wayland compositor (river) and I've configured it to draw a red border around focused windows and a black border around unfocused windows.  For Qt and other non-GTK apps this works fine, the borders are drawn and no window decorations are present.  But GTK apps, such as Firefox and Nautilus, don't have the borders drawn and keep drawing the min,max,close buttons.
I've seen several threads from KDE describing how to tell GTK apps to use Plasma's theme but I already have done that. It just themes the min-max-close buttons as Breeze.  I don't want them there at all!
I don't think the issue is specific to the compositor river.  I was able to reproduce it in hyprland so I think it's a GTK issue.
Is there some environment variable I have to enable or do I have to manually override the gtk theme to match what all other apps are doing by default?
I've found ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini and set gtk-decoration-layout= but that's had no effect.  Maybe I need to log out or something to apply the changes or maybe that file is being overridden by half a dozen other gtk config files.  Either way, it doesn't address the borders not being drawn which is the main problem for me.

After fiddling with the following:

~/.confg/gtk-3.0/gtk.css,
~/.confg/gtk-3.0/settings.ini,
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preference button-layout ''
export GTK_CSD=0
export MOZ_ENABLE_WAYLAND=0

and flipping between sway, hyprland, and river I was able to get buttons to disappear with the blank gtk-decoration-layout= setting in settings.ini and adding custom css to gtk.css
decoration {
  border: 2px solid #FF0000;
}
decoration:backdrop {
  border: 2px solid #AAAAAA;
}

environment variables didn't seem to do anything.
All that said.  I couldn't revert the changes in hyprland or sway.  It's like I was hallucinating that it didn't work in Hyprland when it always worked out of the box.  Sway in particular had none of these problems.  Both of those compositors are stripping all GTK window decorations and replacing them with their own.  The river dev said this was an issue with GTK's protocols being outdated and has a PR to update GTK.
update: there was an entry in river's wiki for this all along.
